# Jquery selects too many elements on mouseclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, click

I want to get the ID of an element that I click. It should only give me the ID if it has one.

I have this code to alert me the element ID:

```
$("[id]").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id_name = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(id_name);
});
```

But I only want the foremost element's ID.

I have a button inside a div, both with an id-attribute. If I click the button, I only want the ID of the button. However, my script alerts me of both the buttons ID and the div's ID. Why is that/How can I get only the foremost element's ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because when you click the button, you are also clicking its parent element.

Add this within your function `event.stopPropagation();`

http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is [event propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing), Since you are targeting all elements you can bind the handler to the document object then check whether there is an id for the target element

```
$(document).click(function (event) {
    var id = event.target.id;
    if (!id) {
        return;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    alert(id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button[id]").click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var id_name = $(this).attr("id");
   alert(id_name);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/asimshahiddIT/unm8qjzf/